# Synaptics Touchpad 3 finger swipe for Forward/Back

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics

I've searched and searched but can't find anything concrete for what i'm looking for.

In windows, i can do a 3 finger swipe left or right on the touchpad to go back/forward in a browser or file manager.

I would like to replicate this exact feature in ubuntu 16.04 running chrome.

A lot of suggestions mention easystroke but this is NOT what i'm looking for.

To clarify, I want to swipe the touchpad with 3 fingers in a from left to right or right to left to go back/foward in browsers or file managers.

Not sure why this is so difficult with linux

Answer (score -1):

In ubuntu you have 2 finger scroll.
Along with that you have an option of "Horizontal scroll", it will work with the 2 finger scroll.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I want 3 and 4 finger swiping. nothing to do with scrolling. I want to map 3 finger swipe left/right to back/forward in browsers or file manager. and I'd like to setup actions for 4 finger swipe up/down. It's weird, i see this type of question being asked a lot and all of the answers have nothing to do with the question. Like people aren't reading the questions properly